# Get property of an objects subobject from string

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an object

```
var obj = {
   subObj : {
     value : 1
   }
};
```

Is there any way to get `obj.subObj.value` using a complex property-name string that goes to sub objects?

Example (that doesn't work)

```
var attr = "subObj.value";
return obj[attr];
```

Comment: You have the answer in your own question: obj.subObj.value

Comment: I need to use a string. That's why the question title and question say ""string"

Comment: `attr.split(".").reduce( (result, prop) => result[prop], obj )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you can't.**

---

You can split and loop over every attr.

```js
var obj = {
   subObj : {
     value : 1
   }
};

var attr = "subObj.value";

var result = obj;
attr.split('.').forEach((c) => result = result[c]);

console.log(result);
```

**Or you can use reduce:**

```js
var obj = {
   subObj : {
     value : 1
   }
};

var attr = "subObj.value";
var result = attr.split('.').reduce((a, c) => a[c], obj);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no notation to do this in JavaScript but you could use something like this:

```js
var obj = {
   subObj : {
     value : 1
   }
};
var attr = "subObj.value";
var result = attr.split(".").reduce((a, c) => a[c], obj);
console.log(result)
```